# Configuring Rails CSS Caching with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, passenger, mod-rails

I am using **Passenger** and Rails' `:cache => true` to cache all my css into one big file. Deploys are done via **Capistrano**.

Now sometimes(!), the mem-generated `all.css` file can't be found after the app is restarted (and I get an error in the log)

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/all.css" with {:method=>:get}):
  passenger (2.2.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:81:in `process_request'
  passenger (2.2.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:203:in `main_loop'
```

Placing another `restart.txt` file manually or a `cap deploy:restart` will resolve the issue.

It's not a big thing, but it's always tedious to check and fix. Anybody has an idea what I am doing wrong?

### Edit

My `deploy:restart` looks like this (exactly what I am doing manually).

```
desc "Restarting mod_rails with restart.txt"
task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
end
```

Also I am not using any special (external) CSS files in my caching.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "clear", "application", "contracts", :cache => true %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your deploy you should be running (as part of the deploy:restart task):

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

This will let Passenger know it needs to reload the Rails stack for the new code, and the new stylesheets will get cached upon the first request.

What does your current deploy:restart task look like?

Comment: I would also recommend updating Passenger to 2.2.5 for good measure.  2.2.2 was released back in April and it's continually under development with a few solid releases since then.

Comment: I included the listing - it's as you would recommend the `touch`. I might use this evening to upgrade the production server to 2.2.5 and see if this helps on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This specific issue is caused when the list of stylesheets with the cache option contains at least one external stylesheet. It happens only the very first time the app is started.

```
stylesheet_link_tag "foo.css", "/bar.css", "http://example.org/file.css", :cache => true
# crash
stylesheet_link_tag "foo.css", "/bar.css", :cache => true
# OK
```

Comment: Never even knew that one could use external CSS files in caching. However it's not the case in my situation.